# Not able to compile C/C++ code that's using ncurses

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, ncurses

I've just discovered ncurses and have just started learning it, however the examples in my tutorial don't compile on my computer.

I had to install ncurses manually and did so by entering "apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev". I had to do this because before having done so I got an error saying that I could not "#include ".

Installing it worked, but now I get this error instead:

```
touzen@comp:~/learning_ncurses$ g++ -o hello_world hello_world.cpp
/tmp/ccubZbvK.o: In function `main':
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `initscr'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `printw'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `refresh'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `stdscr'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `wgetch'
hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `endwin'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code I compiled looks like this:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
int main(){
    initscr();
    printw("Hai thar world...");
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Why do I get this error. And even more importantly, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

you have to link the ncurses library

```
g++ -o hello_world hello_world.cpp -lncurses
```

Comment: I'm quite new to C++ so this concept is new to me. Do I always have to do this whenever I'm using a library not included in the compiler?

Comment: Yes. The header file allows your code to compile by matching a function declaration to calls in your code. The linker's job is to find the *actual runnable code* for every function used in your program, and that's by specifying the encapsulating library name at link-time (as well as the object files for your own code).

Comment: Exactly - you need to link to all libraries, even the standard ones.

Comment: The only reason you haven't realized this so far is that GCC automatically links `libc` (unless you tell it not to do so with -ffreestanding)

Comment: it is the common behaviour in other compilers too

Comment: Just a note for cmake users and kdevelop 4.2 users with cmake: In cmakelists.txt add this line: `target_link_libraries(executablename "-lncurses")` and it will compile `executablename` with `-lncurses` flag.

Comment: Linker flags should follow sources and object files, see comment #11 [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ncurses/+question/51319).

Comment: Had exactly same problem as OP but a bit different: I was following very basic hello world tutorial for ncurses and the tutorial explained how to compile, like this: `g++ -lncurses helloworld.cpp` which give same error as OP. So my problem was I needed the explanation that `-lncurses` **has to be at the end of the compiling command.**