# ncurses library compile error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, ncurses

I have looked at similar question on this site and googled why this is happening but have tried these solution[not able to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538059/not-able-to-compile-c-c-code-thats-using-ncurses), [difference between ncurses and curses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517756/whats-the-difference-between-lcurses-and-lncurses-when-compiling-c-using-ncur), [another compile error](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/several-undefined-reference-to-error-when-compiling-a-c-programm-186781/), but I am still having the problem with the error `undefined reference to stdscr` and `wgetch` the compiler is finding the library as far as I can figure out as I used `find` to locate the curses library and entered the full location in the `#include` line.

my code is as follows

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int first_line(char);
int main(){

    char c = 0;

    while((c = getch())!=EOF){
        first_line(c);

    }   

    return 0;
}

int first_line(char c){
    if (c != '\n' && c != '\r'){
            putchar(c);
        do{
            c = getch();
            putchar(c);}
            while( c !='\n');

    }
    else return 0;

    return 0;
}
```

If you can point to what I've missed or am doing wrong I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ncurses.h` is a header file (containing declarations), not a library (containing code that implements those declarations).

The error message you're seeing is from the linker, not from the compiler.

If you're using gcc, you need to add either `-lcurses` or `-lncurses` to the compiler command line (*after* your source file name).

For example, on my system I copied your source to `c.c`, and I can compile and link it using either

```
gcc c.c -o c -lcurses
```

or

```
gcc c.c -o c -lncurses
```

Comment: Thanks all good. Now the program just doesn't work but that i can fix lol